# JavaDB demo folder is missing

Tags: javadb, demo

I installed the whole enchilada - Netbeans 7.4 All (204MB download). According to the documentation, I should have JavaDB and Glassfish and everything else.

I am trying to learn JavaDB by using the tutorials at http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html

However, the tutorials keep referring to a demo folder that I do not have. I have done some research and it appears that I am missing a lot of sample code that is needed for these. If it does not come with the IDE, where can I get the demos?

RK

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is (and isn't) included with NB and the jdk, but by downloading from

http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html

you'll get the same bits as the tutorial is referring to. Btw. 10.6 is a bit dated, 10.10 is the latest.